# Delay in drawing rectangles around contours

Tags: opencv

Im writing abandoned objects detector but I have a problem. For each object found I want to draw a rectangle around it but with 10 sec delay (find contour -> wait 10 sec -> draw rect around the contour) but I dont know how to implement that delay.
I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> C++: void drawContours(InputOutputArray image, InputArrayOfArrays
> contours, int contourIdx, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int
> lineType=8, InputArray hierarchy=noArray(), int maxLevel=INT_MAX,
> Point offset=Point() )
>
> contourIdx – Parameter indicating a contour to draw. If it is negative, all the contours are drawn.

So you basically can do:

```
Find contours here (not shown)

for (int i=0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
{
    drawContours(image,contours, i,...); //the "i" here shows we are drawing just the i-th contour at an iteration.
    cvWaitKey(10000);
}
```

I am pretty sure that opencv can only identify all the contours at one pass, you still will find them in one pass, but you will implement the delay only when drawing them one by one.